# vscode Ctrl Click on reactstrap module import { Nav } from 'reactstrap' shows References window instead of js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

vscode Ctrl Click on reactstrap module import { Nav } from 'reactstrap' shows References window instead of js file

import React, { Component } from 'react';
Ctrl+Click on React and Component opens index.d.ts files

Ctrl+Click on the following opens References window instead of the defintion file.
import { Nav, NavItem, Collapse } from 'reactstrap';
import classnames from 'classnames';

It seems like @types>module_names><> are working but others aren't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following settings in .jsonconfig file helped resolve the issue.
set "module": "CommonJS"
or
set "module": "Node16"

This was earlier set to "ESNext".

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "module": "Node16"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
, "public/src"  ]
}
```

OR

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "module": "CommonJS"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
, "public/src"  ]
}
```